# mvn command not found mac terminal

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to follow this guide to set up hadoop on my eclipse however, when I am at this part:

```
$ mvn install -DskipTests
```

my terminal returns

```
-bash: mvn: command not found
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: See [Installing Maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html).

Answer (score 1):

Install homebrew [the missing package manager for macos](https://brew.sh/)

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Then install maven

`brew install maven`

Answer (score 0):

You need to either install eclipse with maven plugin or use eclipse itself to run the maven commands or set environment variable to the location where maven exists or install maven and configure env variable to the location of maven installation.

You can find instructions to install in this link for windows.

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

try command:`source ~/.bash_profile` in you terminal

Answer (score 0):

One method, you can try, is to use the `login` command from inside the eclipse terminal. It will ask for your system username and password. On successful login, you'll get the fully working eclipse terminal (just like the normal mac terminal).

One heads-up though, after login eclipse terminal will start from the home directory (~/), so it would be better to do a pwd before using the `login` command in order to copy the directory path and do a `cd` to the exact directory you intended. Also, you have to redo it for each new terminal you open.

An EASY way is to use a plugin called **EasyShell** (search it in the marketplace). It makes life easier.